# Laravel's Eloquent: Using Eloquent's many to many sync for multiple items

Tags: php, model, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem with syncing these two models... A manufacturer can belong to multiple sections... problem is that when I do this:

```
    $manufacturer = Solidstav\Models\Manufacturer::find($_POST['manufacturer_id']);

    if (!empty($filename)) {
        $manufacturer->logo = $filename;
    }

    foreach ($languages as $lang) {
        $name = $lang . '_name';
        $desc = $lang . '_description';

        $manufacturer->{$name} = $_POST[$name];
        $manufacturer->{$desc} = $_POST[$desc];
    }

    $saved = $manufacturer->save();
    $manufacturer->sections()->sync($_POST['sections']); // [2, 3]
```

In this case sections are checkboxes in form.

It only saves the value that is first in array. So the above example only saves "2" and I am redirected back to the page where the data came from...

```
// Manufacturer.php
public function sections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Solidstav\\Models\\Section');
}

// Section.php
public function manufacturer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Solidstav\\Models\\Manufacturer');
}
```

This has never happened to me before...

Comment: could you show the whole controller/service logic that runs this line: $manufacturer->sections()->sync([2, 3]);

Comment: @FilipKoblański I am using eloquent outside of laravel, I will update the post and I will also change the topic name because Laravel in title is kind of confusing... didn't even occur to me, sorry.